# select the row with max values grouped by other rows

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table like this

| Name | Project Name | Version deployed | Deployment date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Car | 1.9.8 | 2022-09-23 |
| John | Car | 2.2.4 | 2022-10-15 |
| John | Car | 2.2.5-beta3 | 2022-10-14 |
| John | Plane | 4.9.345 | 2020-03-12 |
| John | Plane | 6.7.89 | 2022-05-05 |
| Jack | Plane | 6.7.89 | 2022-05-05 |
| Jack | Plane | 6.5 | 2022-05-07 |
| Jack | Dog | 4.6.6 | 2022-08-23 |
| Jack | Plane | 6.7.89 | 2022-05-05 |
| ... |  |  |  |

And I would like to have a `SQL` query that selects ONE line grouped by `Name`, `Project Name` and that contains the last deployed version with its deployment date (and possibly other columns not displayed here) and in the example outputs then

| Name | Project Name | Version deployed | Deployment date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| John | Car | 2.2.4 | 2022-10-15 |
| John | Plane | 6.7.89 | 2022-05-05 |
| Jack | Plane | 6.5 | 2022-05-07 |
| Jack | Dog | 4.6.6 | 2022-08-23 |
| ... |  |  |  |

What I tried already different answers from this website, but the ones I found either group on one element or do not provide the other columns.

EDIT:

The Question that this has been marked as duplicate of, asks exactly what I mentioned last: when grouping on one column.
The answers there do not explain how to extend themselves to grouping by multiple columns.

The answer provided by @YuriLevinsky in the comments here, on the other hand, solves exactly what I wanted.

Comment: select name, projectname, version, day from 
        (select name, projectname, version, day, RANK() OVER   
            (PARTITION BY name, projectname ORDER BY day DESC) AS rn
         from table
        ) as aa
     where rn=1

Comment: Yuri Levinsky comment is your answer.

Comment: @YuriLevinsky your comment is the answer. It works great! :D

Comment: dense_rank or rank window  function.